# Why did the Ro­mans per­ceive dark­ness, ᴛᴇ­ɴᴇ­ʙʀᴀᴇ, as a plu­ral count noun?

Tags: classical-latin, etymology, meaning, nuance, plural

Why did the Ro­mans per­ceive dark­ness, *te­ne­brae*, as a plu­ral count noun? <sup>[[Per­se­us cor­pus-search ref­er­ence](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/searchresults?all_words=tenebrae&target=la&phrase=&documents=&page=1&exclude_words=&all_words_expand=on&any_words=)]</sup>

Or per­haps the bet­ter ques­tion is: what spe­cial nu­ance is con­veyed by the
plu­ral *te­ne­brae* which would be lost were the sin­gu­lar *tene­bra* em­ployed in
its stead? The sit­u­a­tion some­how feels dif­fer­ent than the dis­tinc­tion 
be­tween us­ing sin­gu­lar *um*­bra for shad­ow ver­sus plu­ral *um­brae* for shad­ows. But I could well be wrong in that.

[Lewis and Short men­tion](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=tenebrae)
that us­ing *te­ne­brae* for dark­ness is “stronger than *ob­scu­ri­tas*”.  Is the
plu­ral use some­how more ab­stract or fig­u­ra­tive?

I ask be­cause this se­man­ti­cal­ly dis­tinc­tive plu­ral use for dark­ness has not
mere­ly sur­vived in rare ob­scu­ri­ty but in­deed thriv­en in Lat­in’s daugh­ters,
where this spe­cial plu­ral sense is still alive and well. This to me sug­gests that
for the Ro­mans *te­ne­brae* car­ried a shade of mean­ing pow­er­ful enough to
with­stand mil­len­nia of di­a­chron­ic evo­lu­tion es­sen­tial­ly un­changed.

For ex­am­ple, [in French, *té­nè­bres*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/t%C3%A9n%C3%A8bres/77282?q=t%C3%A9n%C3%A8bres#76368)
is a *plu­rale tan­tum* hav­ing no sin­gu­lar at all. In on­ly slight con­trast to that sit­u­a­tion, in both Por­tuguese and
Span­ish the sin­gu­lar does co­ëx­ist be­side the plu­ral, but on­ly as an
oc­ca­sion­al strag­gler. The plu­ral is much more com­mon in both
lan­guages; it some­how seems to car­ry a heav­ier weight to my mind as a
Span­ish speak­er.

The Span­ish have al­ways been con­scious of the Latin plur­al’s sense: in [the
Qui­jote, Cer­van­tes fa­mous­ly used the mot­to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_tenebras_lux) ***Post te­ne­bras spe­ro
lu­cem*** in his ti­tle pages

Por­tuguese has [*trevas*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/treva), where
their dic­tio­nary notes that it’s more used in the plu­ral.  Brazil­ian
Por­tu­guese some­times us­es the old­er and less al­tered form
[tê­ne­bras](https://www.di%C2%ADcio.com.br/tene%C2%ADbras/) in the same spe­cial way.

This same thing al­so hap­pens in the Span­ish de­scen­dant of
*te­ne­brae*, which is [*ti­nie­blas*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZnQw0J4),
fa­mous­ly oc­cur­ring in the ti­tle of Pe­dro Almod­ó­var’s
ground-break­ing Span­ish-lan­guage film, [*En­tre
Tinieblas*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Habits).

Maybe the Ro­man Cath­o­lic Church's re­ten­tion of the Latin sense for the
prop­er noun *Te­ne­brae* (see foot­note) is part a rea­son for the per­sis­tence of the plu­ral,
but it doesn't at all ex­plain the ori­gin for the strong­er, ab­stract sense which we see in Clas­si­cal Latin.

But what does?

---

#### Foot­notes

The [OED de­fines *Te­ne­brae*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/199093) as:

> The name giv­en to the of­fice of matins and lauds of the fol­low­ing day,
>   usu­al­ly sung in the af­ter­noon or evening of Wed­nes­day, Thurs­day, and Fri­day
>   in Holy Week, at which the can­dles light­ed at the be­gin­ning of the ser­vice
>   are ex­tin­guished one by one af­ter each psalm, in mem­o­ry of the dark­ness at
>   the time of the cru­ci­fix­ion. Al­so *at­tribu­tive*.

Comment: Why do you think it was *count*? pluralia tantum would be more accurate.

Comment: @AlexB Because I had not put enough work into my research, having read something unscholarly that mentioned that Latin *tenebra* in the singular actually existed. However, I can find no obvious singular in Perseus now that I look a bit harder. Its descendants are certainly pluralia tantum in French, and almost but not quite 100.00%-always so in Spanish and Portuguese. I actually had to look that up because I’d never heard or read it in the singular in ES or PT, only in the plural, so I take those to be back-formations absent in the original source Latin. But again, I’m not the expert here. :)

Comment: The HP corpus contains only a single easily identifiable instance of singular *tenebra*: http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=tenebra%23

Comment: From the OLD, Apuleius *Metamorphoses* 5.20: *"Omnique isto apparatu tenacissime dissimulato, postquam sulcatos25 intrahens gressus cubile solitum conscenderit, iamque porrectus et exordio somni prementis implicitus altum soporem flare coeperit, toro delapsa nudoque vestigio pensilem gradum paullulatim26 minuens, caecae **tenebrae** custodio liberata lucerna, praeclari tui facinoris opportunitatem de luminis consilio mutuare, et ancipiti telo illo audaciter, prius dextera sursum elata, nisu quam valido noxii serpentis nodum cervicis et capitis abscide."*

Comment: oops, technically it is **a plurale tantum** (pluralia tantum is its plural form).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of dozen or so words of Latin which, like *tenebrae*, are only ever found in the plural form. Curiously, a few of them are also plural in English translation, for example *divitiae*, 'riches', *hiberna*, winter quarters' and *arma*, 'arms'.

For *tenebrae* we would say In English ['in the] shadows', similarly referring to darkness or obscurity as an abstract noun. In looking for nuance, I doubt that the Romans would have had any more difficulty with their word than we English-speakers have with ours. I think that your question may have no logical answer : that it's just a question of custom and usage.

As for the use of both *umbra* and *umbrae*, I guess (no more than that) you might think of the singular, meaning 'shadow', as a concrete noun, *sc.* something that has a form that you can see — even though it has no substance. Its plural can either mean the separate shadows that you can distinguish, or be looked on as an abstract noun, like *tenebrae* (which is considered to indicate a deeper form of obscurity).